# How to add icons and more text inside Settings.bundle. Get more options

Tags: ios, icons, settings.bundle

I am learning iOS development and I have some questions to ask you in my first post.

To learn iOS I do an stupid application which have Settings.bundle. I want to put small images or icons inside it but I can't.

I also write to the right of the PSChildPaneSpecifier the value of a PSToggleSwitchSpecifier

Apple does it, [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkpSY.png):

[image]

I search in [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but I didn't find anything about this. Maybe it is impossible and only Apple can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it's something only Apple can do. Third-party apps are limited in what they can achieve in the settings bundle. The only icon you can have is the app icon on the first page, and the only information on the right hand side will be string values - see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) for details.

Comment: the only information on the right hand side will be string values.

Comment: "On" doesn't count as a string value if it just relates to the value of a toggle switch - the toggle itself will be in the right hand side of the cell in that case. In your example "On" is like a header for the new section, since it has other options in there as well.

Comment: so, If I write that string with an var it would works?
like:
BOOL valueOnOFF = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isEnable"];

Comment: No, that won't work. Where would you put that code? Why do you want the word "on" there instead of just having the switch?

Comment: I don't know where I have to put the code.

I want because I have a list with some animals, each row is a PSChildPaneSpecifier, which show you other screen with PSToggleSwitchSpecifier (and more things).
It would be good if I can see (writed on/off) if an animal is on or off without enter in the animal. 

Like previews image, where you can see Location services is ON, and if you choose, enter and change.
Thanks!

Screenshot: http://imgur.com/qXTXI

Comment: OK, I understand. No, you can't do that.

Comment: yes iOS sucks when Android have a lot of predefined possibilities, you can easily add settings, configure them as you want, icons, filter, iOS doesn't have filter for textfield in settingsbuild

Answer (score 1):

Without being jailbroken you cannot achieve this, Apple simply won't allow it and does not offer a way to do this.